# C# Speech Recognition Contained in Background Worker still running after canceled

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

I am having a issue with my program. There is a background worker that starts on button press and inside this worker is a do loop containing some speech recognition code that monitors for user input and displays it. The bug is as followed. If you cancel the worker on stop/start button the speech recognition engine is still waiting for one more input, and if you click the start button before speaking to clear it out it will now output 2 duplicate results instead of one.

A good portion of the speech recognition code was hack slash copy pasted together to get working, so im not intimately familiar with it.

Program Code: http://pastebin.com/tBXKs5DT

any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Am I misreading your code or is the voice voice recognition event based? I don't see you unbinding the `recognizer.SpeechRecognize` event anywhere. Aren't you just accidentally dual binding the event when pressing the button for a second time.

Comment: From my understanding the way i have it setup is due to the loop inside the BG Worker its constantly monitoring the microphone and when it detects speech with recognizer_SpeechRecognized it runs the code to translate the speech and output it then loops back around to continue monitoring

Comment: Ah yes I see, I indeed misread it! And the double entry is that once, or does it continue to go wrong indefinably?

Comment: Once double entry starts it will remain double for all future voice entries. Infact if you hit stop again, and start it before speaking one last time, you now have triples and so on

Comment: Oooh I see it now, give me a minute to type out a proper awnser

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you loose the cancel reference before your loop reaches the the cancel check. To explain this I'll take a small sample of your code:

```
_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) => {
   do {
        if (_worker.CancellationPending) {
           break;
        }
        //recognize spoken command
    } while (true);
});
```

When you hit the stop button you flag the `_worker` to cancel. But the loop is most likely waiting for you to speek up. Only after you've spoken the loop will continue and check the cancellation flag.

However: When you press start the `_worker` reference is overwritten and reused. At that point you got two loops running. Both looking at the same cancellation flag which is set back to false. So if you then speak up both will process your voice command, see that they do not have to cancel and carry on.

To resolve this your stop button should interrupt the worker thread by calling the [.Interrupt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.interrupt(v=vs.110).aspx) on the `_worker` in your stop event (button2_click). Then inside the do work code you need to have a try/catch for a [interrupt exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadinterruptedexception(v=vs.110).aspx). If the exception is triggered then check if the cancel flag is true, if so then break out of the while loop.

A few extra side notes:

- There is a easier way to listen to voice commands using the RecognizeAsync. Have a look at [this example on msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine(v=vs.110).aspx)
- `File.Exists` already returns a bool. There is no need to compare it to true in your if statements
- When writing more then a 'hello world' program try to give everything a proper name. The code becomes quite the treasure hunt with names like "button1"

**EDIT:**
 A example for the interrupt (Disclaimer: I don't have VS at hand here, so typos might be included)

Setting the cancel flag and interrupting a thread is quite simple. Assuming that your thread (or background worker which is basically a thread) is called `_worker` it looks somewhat like this:

```
_worker.CancelAsync();
_worker.Interrupt();
```

This will trigger a interrupt exception inside that dowork event. Be sure that these exceptions are handled. In your case that would look something like this:

```
_worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler((state, args) => {
   do {
        try {
             if (_worker.CancellationPending) {
                 break;
             }
             //recognize spoken command
         } catch (ThreadInterruptedException) {
               if (_worker.CancellationPending) {
                 break;
               }
               //reaching this would be a odd situation. It means you interrupted your thread without canceling it. 
               //In your case this shouldn't happen, but there are cases in which you would want to support this
         }
    } while (true);
});
```

Comment: What you said makes a lot of sense. I am having trouble figuring out how to call a .interrupt against _worker can you provide a example

Comment: This does not seem to work It does not like the Interupt() claiming backround worker does not contain a definition for 'Interupt' and no extention method 'interupt' accepting a first agrument of type 'background worker' could be found "are you missing a assembly referance"?  I am already referancing System.Threading.